In ansible, how to wait till the host is unreachable and then ignore it to continue to the next task that waits until the host is reachable again?
The requirement is to have a playbook that performs Software upgrade of a node. The node gets rebooted during the upgrade process.
When the upgrade activation command is triggered by certain task (let us say task-4) in the playbook, it takes sometime in between 20 to 40 minutes to become unreachable due to reboot and it takes another 20 to 40 minutes to be reachable again.
I would like to have the immediate task (task-5) wait till the node is unreachable due to reboot, ignore the unreachability to move to the next task (task-6) that waits until the node is reachable again after reboot. I guess I can use wait_for_connection module for task-6.
I would like to know how to implement the task (task-5) that waits for node to become unreachable due to reboot and ignore unreachability to continue to the next task. Please help.

The title of this question seems to be a statement not a question. could you reformulate it? also you have not included any code - are you sure that there is enough for people to be able to give you a good answer??

For this task, you can use ansible wait_for module https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html
The wait_for module waits for a condition to be true before proceeding to the next task. So you can just set a condition for the node to become unreachable so that it will proceed to task 5 after the node becomes unreachable. Something like the following,
    - name: Wait for Node to Become Unreachable
      wait_for:
        host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        port: <port>  # SSH port
        state: absent  # Wait until the node becomes unreachable
      ignore_errors: yes  # Ignore errors (unreachability) and proceed to the next task

